# converting binary to text in linux

Tags: c++, linux, binary

I have a big binary file I have produced by writing an array of float numbers in binary format.

Now how can I simply convert that binary file to text ?

Comment: what binary format did you use?

Comment: I just opened a binary file using ofstream out(blah , ios::out | ios::binary) and wrote in it out.write((char* ) blah, size); .... what format is this?

Comment: Make your goal clearer, please. Do you want to read the values back in and produce formatted output a la `printf`? In that case, an `unpack()` Perl or PHP script would probably much easier than C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the UNIX od command, with the `-t f4` option to read the file as 4 byte floating point values.  The `-A n` option is also useful to avoid printing the file offsets.  Here is the output of an example file that I created.

```
/tmp> od -A n -t f4 b.dump
        -999.876        -998.876        -997.876        -996.876
        -995.876        -994.876        -993.876        -992.876
        -991.876        -990.876        -989.876        -988.876
        -987.876        -986.876        -985.876        -984.876
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reverse the process.

1. Read the file back into an array of floats.
2. Print the array use printf() or your favorite io function.

Any other approach will be ugly and painful; not to say this isn't ugly to start with.